# Java Tracing with for loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, trace

I have tried tracing this but find it kind of hard to figure out whats going on. I also tried debugging but no luck.

```
public class bob {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] numbers = {{1, 0}, {4, 1}, {2, 3}, {1, 4}};
    int[] frequencies = new int[5];

    for (int row = 0; row < numbers.length; row++)
      for (int col = 0; col < numbers[row].length; col++) {
        frequencies[numbers[row][col]]++;
      }
    for (int i = 0; i < frequencies.length; i++)
      System.out.print(frequencies[i] + " ");
  }
}
```

My print out is `1,4,4,1` but eclipse gives me `1,3,1,1,2`
If someone can just trace the first part, I should be able to follow the rest. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Eclipse should have a debugger. What's wrong with using it?

Comment: RE: "*My print out is 1,4,4,1 but eclipse gives me 1,3,1,1,2*"  What does it mean? What is the problem?

Comment: I tried using it but I seem to be getting lost. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: As for your code - it's a nested for loop, basically it's iterating over every element in numbers and incrementing the element in frequencies with that current index. So it should be no surprise that it outputs 1,3,1,1,2.

Comment: As a good practice, you should always add braces to your for/if/while(etc.). Without it, you just make it error-prone and more unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You begin with initializing `frequencies` as a default array of `ints` with values {0,0,0,0,0}.

While iterating through your loops, you access this default array using the indexes provided by the `numbers` array, and then incrementing each int at `frequencies[numbers[row][col]]`. Thus on your first pass, you will increment the 1st element of `frequencies` by 1; on your next pass, you will increment the 0th element of `frequencies` by 1.

Therefore by the end of your iterations, `frequencies` contains the *frequency* of each particular number in `numbers`, from 0 to 4, resulting in a `frequencies` array of {1,3,1,1,2}. Very fun to figure out, and straightforward once you do! Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, that made a lot more sense maybe I just needed a break from it. I don't know why I was wrecking my head over. Now that I see it its like duhhh! thanks again everyone and leoshnoire :D

Comment: No problem, it was a pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

Your print out should not be `1,4,4,1`, because you are *looping over frequencies* ***5 times***.

`1,3,1,1,2` is the correct output.

I would suggest you add braces to the outer `for-loop` *(rows)*, because if you add code after the inner-loop it will not be a part of the main loop.